# Can i use parent router-outlet for display child->child rout?

Tags: angular

For example, I have the following routes:

`/page` - this page have router-outlet

When user click on button, he goes to `/page/detail/1`.

The route changes, but the content does not redraw.

What i doing wrong?

Can i use parent router-outlet for display child->child rout?

If I can't do that, then how correct?

```
const appRoute:Routes=[{
  path:'',redirectTo:'/page',pathMatch:'full'
}]

const pageRoutes:Routes=[
  {
    path:'page',component: ListComponent
    ,children:[{
      path:'detail/:id',component:DetailComponent
    }]

  }];
```

If i change to:

```
const appRoute:Routes=[{
  path:'',redirectTo:'/page',pathMatch:'full'
},{ path:'page/detail/:id',component:DetailComponent}]
```

then work, but this see ugly and I think there's a better solution...

[stackblits](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-esimxd?embed=1&file=src/app/page/components/list/list.component.html)

Comment: What exactly is your question? What do you want to achieve? What does "but this see ugly and I think there's a better solution" mean?

Comment: 'What exactly is your question?'- can i use parent router-outlet for display child=>child 'What do you want to achieve'- after click inside page, detail/:id rendering instead page. 'What does "but this see ugly and I think there's a better solution" mean?' appRoute: Routes explicitly works with components of another module

Answer (score 0):

You can't replace your parent for your children component.

To make use of children routes you need to add a  somewhere inside your parent's template. The children component can only be rendered there.